# How to modify multiple go/golang projects at same time on Visual Studio Code VS?

Tags: go, github, visual-studio-code

I'm working in multiple go/golang project at same time all of them versioned on github. I'm using Visual Studio Code as IDE. For this, I've clone the projects on the same folder and I've opened it on Visual Studio Code. I have to do a modification, for example, in the project A that depends of the project B (both from the same organization), however this modification implies to modify project B too. Then from any go source file on project A I access to code on B but Visual Studio Code shows the code on A stored in go folder from home folder (i.e. /go/pkg/mod/github.com/organization/goproject/core/...). Is there any form to refer to the source code that I've cloned instead of the source code in go folder?

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, this question is essentially "How do I use git repos?" which is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Quick question. Do these "projects" really need to be separate github repositories? Do they have different enough functionality to constitute the separation? I'm thinking not (but may very well be wrong), given that you say if A is modified it implies that B must also be modified. Context: When I began breaking out a maturing product into more manageable pieces, I considered multiple repos, but as it turned out, what was really necessary was just multiple folders and packages in a single repo. This repo has a bare base directory and __two__ related buildable apps relying on the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Clone your repositories **TO** the correct `go/src/github.com/...` path in your $GOPATH and change your imports to such. Point whatever VCS software you are using to these folders and maintain the repos inside your $GOPATH where they are supposed to be. Then there isn't two copies being maintained, just one. Your IDE will know exactly where to go because it's all in one place.

This is the way $GOPATH is *supposed* to work. In Go, you don't keep your project folder outside of the $GOPATH, you put it where it's supposed to go *inside* it. It's a different sort of project foldering system, but Go was designed this way, so it's best to just follow the paradigm even though it's a little confusing at first.